# jQuery functionality wont work when GTM code is added

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager, jquery-events

My JavaScript is as follows in separate js file. It works fine:

```
$( document ).on( 'customEvent1', viewportAdjust ).on( 'customEvent2', function( e1, param2 ) {
// code logic here
 })
```

but, when I add below GTM code into body section:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

My JavaScript  stops working. I read on some post to rename dataLayer to dataLayer1. In this case my JavaScript works but it's affecting Google tracking.

I read this post http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-problems-with-gtm-listeners/
but in my code I haven't used `return false` anywhere I am just returning object though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you rename the dataLayer, then you would have to use the new name everywhere else you need to interact with it. But typically, GTM code shouldn't cause your JS to stop working. Curious though, how do you determine that it's GTM's fault?

Comment: Is there any specific error in the browsers console ? "Stops working" is not much to go on. Maybe it's some tag inside the tag manager, not GTM itself ?

Comment: @nyuen - my page was working fine earlier but it stops working when I added GTM code. JavaScript works fine if I remove GTM

Comment: @EikePierstorff - I checked code in IE, FF, chrome but its not giving any error in console. only clue is in case  if I remove GTM code my customEvent2 function fire (code logic works) but it stops firing when I add GTM code

Comment: Probably you have some another JS-scripts which are using JS global variable with name "dataLayer". And when you are adding GTM snippet, they are conflicting to each other(but after renaming of GTM dataLayer they are not).

Comment: @buttersmai Thanks for the hint. I searched my whole project directory but this variable is used only once i.e. in GTM code

Comment: Then you may check other tags, implemented in GTM: some of them may cause JS-error. And after you are removing GTM, these tags are disabled and do not crashing JS for website

Comment: GTM is probably including jQuery and overriding your version. Check if this is the case in the gtm.js script. Check how you have your tags and events set up in GTM and possibly use the jQuery.noConflict option or scope your code so that it doesn't interfere with any other code on the page, regardless of jQuery version.